# adding tile with AddTileAsync() causes exception

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

I try to add new tile into Microsoft Band from Windows Phone 8.1 (SDK from July 2015),

but when I add new tile (by included code below), I got dialog to allow third-party tile. After this dialog is Band synced and after I recieve this exception:

> {Microsoft.Band.BandIOException: Failed to connect to the target band.
>   ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. Only one usage
>   of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
>   permitted.
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   Microsoft.Band.Store.BluetoothTransportBase.Connect(RfcommDeviceService
>   service, UInt16 maxConnectAttempts)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- ...

with code:

```
 using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
 {
     try
     {
         IEnumerable<BandTile> tiles = await bandClient.TileManager.GetTilesAsync();
         foreach (var t in tiles)
         {
             if (await bandClient.TileManager.RemoveTileAsync(t))
             {
             }
          }
          var remaining = await bandClient.TileManager.GetRemainingTileCapacityAsync();
          if (remaining == 0)
          {
              return;
          }

          Guid tileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
          BandTile tile = new BandTile(tileGuid)
          {
              Name = "BandTestTile",
              SmallIcon = smallIcon,
              TileIcon = tileIcon,
          };
          await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile);
          await bandClient.NotificationManager.ShowDialogAsync(tileGuid, "Hello", "Hello world!");

           Guid messagesPageGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
           PageData pageContent = new PageData(
                 messagesPageGuid,
                 0,
                 new WrappedTextBlockData(
                 (Int16)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message1,
                 "This is the text of the first message"),
                 new WrappedTextBlockData(
                 (Int16)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message2,
                 "This is the text of the second message")
                );

            await bandClient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(tileGuid, pageContent);
      }
      catch (BandException ex)
      {
      }
  }
```

Do you have some idea, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That exception generally means that there are multiple applications (or multiple threads within a given application) attempting to communicate with the Band at the same time.  Only a single IBandClient "connection" is allowed at any given time.

- Ensure no other applications (such as background tasks) are using the Band
- Ensure all uses of IBandClient in your application are properly disposed of before the code shown above is executed.